# How to select body except one element?

Tags: jquery, html, selector, except

I'm using a color-picker which should be hidden when a click is made anywhere outside it. 
The problem is, it disappears even when the click is made inside the picker.

```
$('body :not(#picker)').click(function() {
    $('#picker').fadeOut();
});
```

I tried this, but it would show the picker and hide it immediately.
Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to obtain the element that was clicked:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id != "picker") {
        $("#picker").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want to use *window* or *html* instead of *body* since the body might not cover the whole window area.

Comment: @Jari, I would go with `document`, then. I went with `body` in my answer because that's the element used by the questioner.

Comment: You just save my day! +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'picker') {
        return;
    } else {
        $('#picker').fadeOut();
    }
});
```